# Reduced homology and colimits

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

I would like to prove that colimits commute with reduced homology, i.e that 
if $ X = \operatorname{colim}\limits_{n \in \Bbb{N}} X_n$, then

$$
\displaystyle\tilde H_k(X) = \operatorname{colim}\limits_{n \in \Bbb{N}} \tilde H_k(X_n).
$$

Moreover, I would really like to deduce this only from the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms. Do you think this is possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't possible because it's not true.

Comment: @Qiaochu Are you sure? Here the limits are direct limits, I'm pretty sure it's true in that case. I don't remember the full proof off the top of my head, but it has to do with some sort of compacity argument ($\Delta^n$ is compact basically).

Comment: This is done from the axioms in May's *Concise* book in chapter 14. For singulat homology it is almost obvious: every chain is in a finite stage of the limit, as it has compact image.

Comment: If the OP intends to only discuss *directed* colimits then that should be specified.

Comment: @Qiaochu Well the notation $\operatorname{colim}_{\color{red}{n \in \mathbb{N}}}$ is suggestive...

Comment: His spaces are indexed by integers!

Comment: @Lehs Please do not introduce terrible typography like that, there is a reason if limit indices are not displayed stacked in inline math... And that `\displaystyle` does absolutely nothing.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Thanks for teaching me that!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Thanks I'll take a look at May's book